# new array with additional element does not visualize

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following diagram https://jsfiddle.net/r96upg74/5/

I create a new array also called data with one more element 'Total' at the end using the following code:

```
var value0Sum = 0,
    value1Sum = 0;

value0Sum = d3.sum(data, function(d){return d[values[0]];});
value1Sum = d3.sum(data, function(d){return d[values[1]];});

data = function (array) {
        r = array.map(function (d) {
            return { id: d.id, value1: d[values[0]], value2: d[values[1]] }} 
        );
    return r.concat([{id:"Total", value1: value0Sum, value2: value1Sum}]);
}(data);
```

It results in: https://jsfiddle.net/r96upg74/7/

However, diagram does not visualize the new data properly.

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some confusions in your code.

This loop is very weird:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    d.value = +d[values[i]];
    return d;
  }
});
```

You assign something in `d.value` and then stop the loop, so you will never go further than `i=0`

I removed it because you don't need it.

Then your problem is that in your second fiddle, you transform the data which used to have the keys `id, M, N` in a data with keys `id, value1, value2`.

I have changed that with `M` and `N` and it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/3860zcc3/

Comment: value1 and value2 are properties of a new array, they don't really have to be named M and N. as well as "id"

Comment: I used similar loop in this case https://jsfiddle.net/Slava32/x5f5xpyb/8/
and it works just fine. Also the initial data was used to create a new array "data".

Comment: The thing is later I'll integrate this code into Microstrategy and connect it with data from there. The property names of the object will not stay M and N in that case, but will have any other names generated with report. That's why basically I use this loop and create new variable "values" before.

Comment: @RostyslavaRomaniuk I get it, so I've made a new version where `M` or `N` are never hardcoded, but instead read from your `values` array: https://jsfiddle.net/mmL1qd24/

Comment: I'm new to d3 and javascript, and probably i'm doing something wrong. But I have two diagrams which work very well with similar loop and data changes. And if you type console.log(data) after data = function (array) {...}(data); you will see that the new data array is created just like I wanted it. That's why I think the main issue is with the code after...

Comment: Note that the first loop is still not being used. In the second chart you gave in a comment, removing the loop doesn't seem to affect the chart either.

Comment: yes, I see. Thank you! It visualizes now the code but still not sure it does it right. Because as you can see from the data, the sums of M and N should be different, but it  visualizes like they are equal.

Comment: You are so right about the loop! It seems useless! I deleted it from other codes where I used it and it seems that it does not do any harm but does not chage anything either. THANKS

Comment: @Slava32 indeed. That is because you have two defferent scales, y0 and y1 for the left bars and right bars. Hence in the total, both values reach the top of their own scale. I assume what you want is a common scale for every bar, which range from 0 to the max value. I've done yet another version, with a unique `y` scale instead of `y0` and `y1`: https://jsfiddle.net/3rqpxypr/

Comment: data.push(total); doesn't create a new array but just adds another object at the end of the initial data array, right?
I tried to integrate the code into Microstrategy and when I connect the data and wanna see the visualization it returns an error in console "data.push is not a function".

Comment: Yes indeed. If you want to let the initial array untuched you can write `data = data.concat([total])`. As for why `data.push` is not a function this is weird since data should be an array. Can you log `console.log( typeof data, Array.isArray(data), data )` and see what it is?

Comment: I think it behaves weird probably because Microstrategy doesn't allow to make changes to initial array. Just assumption. Anyway, with new array it should work now. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I really don't know about Microstrategy so can't help on this front, but I'm glad you could sort out your issues